# How to avoid same post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am not familiar with php and wordpress, but I want this feature in my WordPress blog that if a post (use post_title as key) is already exist then stop inserting.

I have found the wp_insert_post() function, but I don't know how to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
if ( post_exists( $title ) == 0 ) {
    wp_insert_post($args);
}
```